# TLS upgrade impact over FTP/FTPS/SFTP

Tags: ssh, ssl, sftp

We planned to upgrade TLS version in our unix servers. Currently we are using FTP,SFTP and few FTPS connections to transfer files. So, If we will upgrade TLS version, will it impact FTP,SFTP and FTPS connections in unix servers?

If yes, could you please let me know pre/post actions needs to be taken to ensure everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Plain FTP uses no encryption at all, so no impact expected there.

SFTP is based on SSH, not SSL/TLS so no impact expected there either.

FTPS is FTP over SSL/TLS, and TLS version upgrade may affect the workload of encrypted connections. But you said you have only a few of those. So unless your FTPS servers are on the border of being overloaded right now, there should be no significant impact.

So, pre-action: check if FTPS servers are close to being overloaded and if necessary, add more CPU power to have a comfortable power reserve before upgrading.